# iOS: Making a network call using Alamofire and want to push the next view controller after the network call is done

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch, race-condition

I am basically getting a race condition between the network call populating the singleton datastore and the first view controller showing the data. After the first view controller is shown there is no data but if I reload the view then the data will be there. So how do I only push the view controller after the network calls are done? Thanks. Here is my current code:

```
     guard let username = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    TFTINetworkManager.shared().login(username: username, password: password){ loginSuccessful in
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        if loginSuccessful {
            TFTINetworkManager.shared().getUserInfo { _ in
                let VC = TFTIHomeFeedVC.createFromStoryboard()
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unsuccessful Login", message: "Did you provide the right login credentials", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I basically had nested network calls, and called the completion handler of the outer network call as the completion value for the nested network call.